# Trying to create a series of dialogue where each one will have a pre and next

Tags: java

I have 3 dialogs:dlgCreateBot, mdlgTemplate, indicatorAddRemove

Every dialog has a next button. So dlgCreateBot next button will bring up mdlgTemplate, mdlgTemplate next button will bring up  indicatorAddRemove.

The last 2 have a pre buttons. mdlgTemplate pre button will bring up dlgCreateBot, and indicatorAddRemove pre button will bring up mdlgTemplate.

So we have something like this
dlgCreateBot <> mdlgTemplate <> indicatorAddRemove.

I cannot figure out how to have indicatorAddRemove go back to mdlgTemplate if pre button is pressed.

I now we are not suppose to use goto but that would make this so simple

```
dlgTemplate mdlgTemplate;
boolean isAgain=false;
    do {
        dlgCreateBot mdlgCreateBot = new dlgCreateBot(null);
        if (!mdlgCreateBot.isOk)
            return false;
        String tempName=mdlgCreateBot.tempName;
        mdlgTemplate = new dlgTemplate(null,"test",true);
        if (!mdlgTemplate.isOk)
            return false;
        isAgain=mdlgTemplate.isPre; 
        ted++; 
    } while(isAgain);

// how can I make this go back to dlgTemplate
// if pre button is pressed?????     

    indicatorAddRemove mindicatorAddRemove = new indicatorAddRemove(null,true);

    if (!mindicatorAddRemove..isPre)
        {
            WHAT DO I DO TO GO BACK TO dlgTemplate
        }

    if (!mindicatorAddRemove.isOk)

    return true;
```

Comment: Consider utilizing and Array or Collection.

Comment: Is it possible that all the three dialogs are visible at the same time? Or is it that only one dialog is visible at a time?

Comment: @Ted pottel, If I understand you correctly, you could use something like this `do { switch(idOfPressedButton) case 1: ShowFirstDialog();break; case 2: ShowSecondDialog();break; ... default: break; } while(yourExitCondition)`